# In SQLAlchemey, Can I add new object to the relationship object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I add new object to the relationship object?

```
Class Parent():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(10))
    child = relationship('Child', backref='parent', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

Class Child():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    name = Column(String(10))

parent = Parent('parent1', [Child(name='child1'), Child(name='child2')])
session.add(parent)
session.commit()
```

The above code is insert one parent and its 2 child.

My Question is,

Can I add new child from exist parent like this?

```
parent = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id=1).first()
parent.children.append(Child(name='child3'))
session.merge(parent)
```

I tried above it shows the IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) datatype mismatch u'UPDATE child.

Had I made any mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
parent = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id=1).first()
child = Child(parent=parent, name='child3')
session.add(child)
```